# How to make Corda smart contracts to run inside Intel SGX enclaves?

Tags: blockchain, corda, sgx, enclave

Conclave – a play on enclave – is the name for R3’s research product which hopes to make ‘Enclave oriented computing’ (EoC) accessible to developers.

Basically trying to understand how to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

You can get a Conclave Developer Preview https://www.r3.com/conclave-beta/

Here is also a video by our platform engineer Mike Hearn demoing the project: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1kEwNsiSQJk

Comment: Isnt there a doc related to the same ?